# How to debug C++ DLL(or .so) file in C# .NET project in visual-studio-code (UBUNTU)?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, dll, ubuntu-22.04

When enable native debugging was activated in visual studio on windows, I could do debug if the DLL file was also compiled as debug. I have successfully migrated the project to Ubuntu, C++ DLL functions work in the code in C# .NET project but I can't debug it. I couldn't find the enable native debugging part in visual studio code settings. I probably need to edit launch.json or task.json but I don't know how.

Comment: First big question mark: You say you're on Ubuntu, but the path uses backslashes and the file's extension is ".dll", non of which make sense on a Linux system. Just a suggestion, create a similar project from scratch and compare the generated setup with your setup.

Comment: It is not a problem. DLL functions are working correctly as I said. I just can't debug into it. If you know how to debug into DLL just say that. I'll edit the question again. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: *but I can't debug it* -- Start Visual Studio, load the DLL project, run your program, and attach to the process via the Debug menu.

Comment: I use visual studio code because Ubuntu does not have visual studio. So I don't know how to do what you said with vs code.

Comment: So you can't attach to the running process in VS Code?  Then that makes it lacking in debugging options.

Comment: Yes, i couldn't find a way but must be..